# Fiddler XML Parsing

Tags: javascript, json, xml, fiddler

FiddlerScript is [capable of JSON parsing and modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094692/can-i-modify-json-responses-using-fiddler-scripts). For example, the following addition to `OnBeforeResponse` will sneakily replace [Ipify's](https://www.ipify.org/) returned external IP address with `127.0.0.1`:

```
if (oSession.url == "api.ipify.org/?format=json"){
    var j = GetResponseJson(oSession);
    j["ip"] = "127.0.0.1";
    SetResponseJson(oSession, j); 
}
```

where `GetResponseJson` and `SetResponseJson` are helper functions I made from Eric's linked answer:

```
static function GetResponseJson(oSession: Session){
    return Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString()).JSONObject;
}
static function SetResponseJson(oSession: Session, j){  
    oSession.utilSetResponseBody(Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonEncode(j));
}
```

This is great for modifying JSON payloads intercepted by Fiddler.

My question is:

- Is there an equivalent way to parse and modify **XML** in FiddlerScript?

Answer (score 5):

FiddlerScript uses JScript.NET, and thus can reference .NET assemblies, including `System.Xml`, which contains the `XmlDocument` class.

First, in Fiddler > Tools > Fiddler Options > Extensions, add a reference to `System.Xml.dll`:

[image]

Next, at the top of FiddlerScript, reference it:

```
import System.Xml;
```

At that point, you can create `XmlDocument` objects:

```
var x = new XmlDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom column from a node in XML in the response, you need to use FiddlerScript.

What is required when you have loaded the System.xml reference, in the FiddlerScript (Rules > Customize Rules), you can add :

```
public static BindUIColumn("Request")
    function testXmlColumn(oSession: Session){
        if (oSession.oResponse != null && oSession.oResponse["Content-Type"] == "text/xml; charset=utf-8") {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.LoadXml(oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString());

            var xPathString = '/an/XPath/Expression';

            var xmlNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xPathString);

            return xmlNode.InnerText;
      }
    return "";
}
```

Obviously, you need to replace `/an/XPath/Expression` with an XPath expression. This is fairly simple language to match a node.